# Heroku rails deployment "at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I am trying to deploy my Rails app on Heroku however I face two h10 errors:

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" ... dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

and

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" ...  dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

As I read in other posts I ran `heroku console`.

I got this answer:

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined local variable or method `acts_as_votable' for Comment (call 'Comment.connection' to establish a connection):Class (NameError)
```

When I am doing a `heroku run rake db:migrate`, I get this:

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant ForestLiana`
```

Here is my `Gemfile` :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.0'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'    
gem 'turbolinks'    
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'    
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'forest_liana'
  gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.10.0'
end
```

Is it due to gem version? How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deploying code to Heroku, it does not install gems defined in the `:development` group in your `Gemfile` since those gems are usually not needed when actually running your application in production.

In your case however, you have added the `acts_as_votable` gem in the development group. Since your models are relying on it, you should define it outside of any group in your `Gemfile` so that it is always installed.

When checking your stacktrace, you can see that the `acts_as_votable` method you call on your `Comment` class is not available on Heroku. This could give you the hint that the gem adding this method is either not installed or is not loaded somehow.